# How to create and apply patch files, skipping over file versions, if needed?

Tags: linux, svn, unix, diff, patch

First, an example to clarify my question. I create a file called `file1`, where the digit indicate the file revision. The file contains only one line:

```
~$ cat file1
test1
```

I modify that file, and add a line containing `test2`. I save that file under new revision, calling it `file2`. Calling `cat` on that file yields:

```
~$ cat file2
test1
test2
```

I then make a third change, again saving that file under new revision `file3`, with contents:

```
~$ cat file3
test1
test2
test3
```

So my question is this: If I wish to create a patch that would apply changes made in `file3` on `file1`, skipping over revision `file2`, how can I do that? Is it possible?

Basically I need a patch that updates contents of `file1` from:

```
~$ cat file1
test1
```

To

```
~$ cat file1
test1
test3
```

Is this doable? Thank you.

Comment: would version control make sense?  if these changes are happening in a code project, you could use something like `git cherry-pick` to pick only the revisions you want to include. might not make sense for your use case, though, if these files are widely distributed across your system.

Comment: You have this tagged `svn` and yet you are *manually* tracking revisions by updating the filename?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, for the sake of this example. I work with SVN though. If I can't do this task locally, what reason do I have to believe that SVN can pull it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing looks like a poor man's VCS, with each file representing a revision. The differences between two consecutive files (revisions) represent a changeset. It sounds like you want to create a patch for a particular changeset:

```
$ diff file2 file3 > changes.patch
```

and apply it to an earlier revision:

```
$ patch file1 < changes.patch
$ cat file1
test1
test3
```

Or alternatively, perhaps you want to create a patch to reverse a particular changeset:

```
$ diff file2 file1 > changes.patch
```

and apply it to your latest revision:

```
$ patch file3 < changes.patch
$ cat file3
test1
test3
```

For this particular example, the first approach fails if you use a contextual or unified diff. Neither approach is particularly robust in a more general case. For example, if you need to patch an entire source tree instead of a single file, the names of the files to be updated will be pulled out of the patch file itself.

You should use a real version control system so you don't have to track revisions manually. `svn merge` allows you to "patch" a working copy using a specific changeset. You can do this to "rollback" one or more changesets. Say your repo contains a single file, `file`, and you've committed three revisions:

```
# file at r1:
test1

# file at r2:
test1
test2

# file at r3:
test1
test2
test3
```

You want to reverse the second changeset. First check out the file at r3 (HEAD):

```
$ svn checkout svn://path/to/repo
A    repo/file
Checked out revision 3.
```

Next do a reverse merge of the changes from changeset 2 (i.e. the changes made between revision 1 and revision 2) into your working copy:

```
$ cd repo
$ svn merge -c -2 svn://path/to/repo
```

In this particular case, you will get a conflict which you will have to manually resolve. In real-world repositories, you may or may not get conflicts when you try to reverse earlier changesets.

Comment: Much appreciated for the explanation!